# "No new release found" when trying to upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, 19.10

I've seen a few posts talking about upgrading from LTS to LTS where we would need to wait 3 months for version 20.04.1. But I'm a 19.10 user and I'm getting the "No new release found" message. I've installed 20.04 on a different computer from the ISO but I can't wipe my main setup for various reasons.

Why am I not getting the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/upgrade-ubuntu-19-10-to-ubuntu-20-04

If the problem persists, try going to

Software & Updates> Updates> Notification me of a new Ubuntu version: and change to "For long-term support version"

Then call the

```
update-manager -d
```

command and it showed me an update window. Perhaps it will help you too

Comment: I was advised not to use the developer option (-d) right now because it may have unexpected results

Comment: @OpenTangent, if you don't wona used (`-d`) you can used (`-p`) or (`--proposed`) **Upgrade using the latest proposed version of the release upgrader**, all list of flag you can see if call command `update-manager -h`

Comment: Ah thanks. I ended up backing everything up and reformatting, but I'll keep that in mind for next time